# Thread Processing

Tags: c, pthreads, semaphore

Create a thread. Take a string from user. Generate a message containing users input append with counter value(i). Write to buffer and let parent thread read message when available and display. Please help me with the correction required.
I am unable to fetch the output

The final output is not displayed.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/time.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/select.h>
#include <pthread.h>
#include <semaphore.h>
#define MAX 1024
#define SUCCESS 0
#define FAILURE 1
char store[MAX];
sem_t reader;
sem_t writer;
void *show_count(void *arg)
{
    int i=0;    
    int ret_val=-1;
    int counter=0;
    struct timeval tv;
    printf("\nPlease enter the value of counter......");
    scanf("%d",&counter);
    tv.tv_usec=0;
    for (i=0; i<3; i++)
    {
        char buff[20];
        printf("\n%d",i);
        tv.tv_sec=counter;
        ret_val=select(3,NULL,NULL,NULL,&tv);
        if(0!=ret_val)
        {
            perror("\nSelect()...");
            exit(-1);
        }
        else
        {
            sprintf(buff,"%d",i);
            sem_wait(&writer);
            strcat(store,(char *)arg);
            strcat(store, buff);
            sem_post(&reader);
            printf("\nstring concatenation done....");
        }    
    }
    return (void*)store;
}

int main()
{
    int ret=-1;
    pthread_t trd;
    pthread_attr_t att;
    pthread_attr_init(&att);
    sem_init(&reader,0,0);
    sem_init(&writer,0,MAX);
    char buffer[MAX];
    char data[MAX];
    printf("\n Please enter a string.....");
    fgets(buffer, MAX, stdin);
    buffer[strlen(buffer)-1]='\0';
    ret=pthread_create(&trd,NULL,show_count,buffer);
    if(0!=ret)
    {
        perror("\nError creating thread.......");
        exit(-1);
    }
    pthread_join(trd,(void **)&data);
    sem_wait(&reader);
    printf("%s",(char *)data);
    sem_post(&writer);
    sem_destroy(&reader);
    sem_destroy(&writer);
    return SUCCESS;
}
```

Comment: If you are trying producers/consumer problem, you are not even close. Please read online material about the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Your problem with nothing printing out is a simple fix. You're printing the value of `data` when you're not actually setting it anywhere.

Changing `printf("%s",(char *)data);` to `printf("%s",(char *)store);` produces the concatenated value.

I'm not entirely clear on what you're supposed to do with the counter input so I'm not going to comment on the validity of the output. I'll edit my post with a more complete response if the output is incorrect and if you would like to provide some clarification.